# How do I add a shadow beneath my action bar in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to get a shadow to appear beneath my action bar, but for some reason the shadow continually appears and begins at the very top of the screen, instead of beneath the action bar. I'm using a CustomView `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` action bar widget in each of my xml layout files. How can I get the shadow to properly appear beneath this action bar instead of at the top? Can I set some kind of divider equal to the height of this custom view before the shadow appears? Can we do something like set the height of the gradient to 50dp but only show the gradient in the last 5-10% of that height?

**My theme:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/teal</item>

    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight & colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->

    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#d7d7d7</item>

    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/actionbar_shadow</item>

</style>
```

**Shadow drawable:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:height="4dp" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:startColor="@color/grey" />
</shape>
```

**Toolbar:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:minHeight="30dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/actionbar_title_r"
        android:id="@+id/ActionBarTitle" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: What else should I show?

Comment: could not see anything wrong

Comment: you may use toolbar and use elevation to it , it will give you shadow effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toolbar will have a shadow only in devices running on API 21 or higher. In order to achieve this effect you can add the property `android:elevation="4dp"` And it will work fine. Hope this helps

Comment: Any particular reason for 4dp?

Comment: Thank you this works. I suppose that's just the height of the shadow. Thanks.

Comment: I Usually add 4dp because it looks nice in the screen in my opinion, and its also What's recommended by google if Im not wrong but you can add and many DPS as you want. Please refer to the material design guidelines for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can try several dp for elevation on the material appBar layout and see the degree of effect it gives. Then you decide how much do you give it.

in the appBar,
android:elevation = "1dp"

play with 2dp, 3dp,4dp and choose whats right for you.